# Integral of $1\over{\sin^2x}$ and $1\over{\sin^4x}$

Tags: integration

Could anyone show me how to find the integral of

$1\over{\sin^2x}$ and $1\over{\sin^4x}$

systematically?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution always works.

Comment: Did you ever learn the derivative of $\cot x$ or $\tan x$?

Comment: Hint: can you rewrite these as $csc^{2}(x)$ and $csc^{4}(x)$ and then proceed that way? Then. you can use [**Integrals**](http://www.integraltec.com/math/math.php?f=csc_n.html#csc2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the change of variables $u = \cot(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$d(\cot{x})=-\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{x}}dx \\
1+\cot^2{x}=\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{x}}
$$